# Post not getting automatic downvote on abuse flag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, down-votes, automation

I [flagged these](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301672/is-there-friction-in-spacetime/301807#301807) as rude and abusive of site resources and ToS. One briefly got an automatic downvote, which disappeared and then reverted, the other never had the automatic downvote. I have refeshed the page.

[image]
[image]

---

There's downvotes now

[image]

I'm adding this to see if there is a delay, they may be from other users.

**Is this a bug?**

---

The automatic flag downvote [worked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203172/triangle-geometry-question/2076804#2076804) 
[image]

*Incidentally it's all the same user on a network nuisance spree*

Comment: it could be that the vote is being canceled out by an upvote. the someone is upvoting those answers

Comment: @Memor-X I **did** wonder about that. hm I hope not. That person would deserve a suspension. We need someone with vote breakdown privileges on Physics to confirm that.

Comment: I think the issue is that automatic downvotes are not pushed through the websocket. You should see it if you reload the page.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes I did, refresh,as mentioned in my post. There are downvotes now, but I no longer know if that is due to more flags, or my flags.

Comment: There was another user upvoting them. It was cancelling out the downvotes. We'll look into it further.

Comment: @JanDvorak [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-vote-totals-without/oibfliilcglieepgkdkahpfiiigdijdd?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) can allow you to see how many up/downvotes a post has without needing 1k rep and anyone can view a user's rep history in their profile

Comment: @Memor-X meh. I can do that without a web browser that ignores my privacy by sticking my name to every screencast I make.http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep

Comment: @Memor-X thank you! Will save the time of posting this. Otherwise it would be a mod flag, so and so is upvoting obvious rubbish

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The downvotes worked fine. Someone just came along and upvoted them. Both personas have been scolded.

Comment: Thanks and I'm glad they've been scolded.

Comment: scolded or scalded.... or both??